# Socket.io server could not catch the request sent by client using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

***this is my Server.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var i=0;

io.on("connection",function(socket){

  console.log("user connected");

 socket.on('message', msg => console.log(msg));

  socket.on("new-msgs",function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    // io.emit("receive-msgs",msg);
  });

  socket.on('test',function(){
      console.log("mounted");

  });

});


http.listen('3000',function(){
  console.log("we are connected");
});
```

and this is my Client(chat.js)

```
import React from 'react';

var Chat = React.createClass({


  getInitialState: function(){
  //  console.log("asdf");
  return{
     messages: [],
     socket : window.io('http://localhost:3000')
  }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
this.state.socket.emit('message', 'Hello world!');
},

handleMessageSubmit() {
  // console.log("handleMessageSubmit");
    this.state.socket.emit('message', 'Hello world!');
},

render: function(){

  return(
    <div className="dSD">
      <h1>chat</h1>
      <button className="custom-datepicker" onClick={this.handleMessageSubmit} >
          click
           </button>
    </div>
  );
}




});


export default Chat;
```

And my colsole output is only 
->we are conected(after i run the socket)
->User connected(after i run the react server)

and on botton click  i get this kinda eror

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1505136488695-1114 
o.create @ socket.io-1.0.0.js:1
o @ socket.io-1.0.0.js:1
r.request @ socket.io-1.0.0.js:1
r.doWrite @ socket.io-1.0.0.js:1

chat:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1505136488695-1114. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

even i **tried this**

```
<button className="custom-datepicker" onClick={this.props.handleMessageSubmit} >
          click
           </button>
```

and

```
<button className="custom-datepicker" onClick={this.state.handleMessageSubmit} >
          click
           </button>
```

**but i get connection refuse error in that case.**

can someone help me please?

Comment: can you try initializing socket.io in your client side like this? `var socket = window.io();` instead of calling it in `getInitialState`

Comment: you can also try using a client side library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client and import socket.io like this: `import io from 'socket.io-client'; 
let socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
`